# Ruby regular expressions match everything between keywords

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

This is about regex in Ruby..

I have a string, that looks like:

"---\n- PARSEFROMHERE anyrthing you can imagine numbers special characters anything ENDPARSEFROMHERE\n PARSEFROMHERE anyrthing you can imagine numbers special characters anything ENDPARSEFROMHERE\n"

How would I match everything in between PARSEFROMHERE ENDPARSEFROMHERE with some regexp?

Thanks!

Comment: In the part where it says "anyrthing you can imagine numbers special characters anything", I can imagine that it might say "foo bar fake_ENDPARSEFROMHERE baz". What should happen in this case?

Comment: no, PARSEFROMHERE is always separated by whitespace

Comment: OK, what if "anyrthing you can imagine numbers special characters anything" contains "foo bar fake ENDPARSEFROMHERE baz"? My imagination is pretty wild, I know, but you *did* say "anything you can imagine"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
regexp = /\bPARSEFROMHERE\b(.*?)\bENDPARSEFROMHERE\b/m
```

Everything is stored into backreference 1. But if for some magical reason you have "unbalanced" delimiters this regex will fail, **miserably**.

Edit:

```
regexp = /\sPARSEFROMHERE\s(.*?)\sENDPARSEFROMHERE\b/m
```

According to your examples PARSEFROMHERE is always preceded-followed by space. Same goes with ENDPARSEFROMHERE but this ends in `\n` so I keed the word boundary anchor there..

Comment: Given the statement _"PARSEFROMHERE is always separated by whitespace"_ you might want to use that explicitly instead of `\b` (given that `foo-bar` has four `\b` in it, for example).

Comment: Funny how Ruby uses `/m` where all other major flavors use `/s`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, as long as "ENDPARSEFROMHERE" doesn't appear within the match:

```
PARSEFROMHERE(.+)ENDPARSEFROMHERE
```

There are problems with this however. This will also match from one ENDPARSEFROMHERE to the next ENDPARSEFROMHERE, so if your start and end tags aren't balanced you'll have problems.

Comment: I can imagine new lines being in there, making this expression fail for two different reasons.